# Audit the log and determine the actions of users in Oracle, as well as the design of the result in the console

Tags: linux, oracle

Is it possible to distinguish quota changes from table space reassignment in the audit log? Here result
I brought `ACTION_NAME` out and found `AUDIT_OPTION` in the documentation, but when I use `SELECT`, it doesn't return `AUDIT_OPTION`. Maybe something can be identified through something. My user first changed the quota to another user in the table space and then changed the default table space to another user. I want to see the lair of these actions.
Here the result is only with `ACTION_NAME`. If I use `ACTION_OPTION` the same result is displayed:[image]

Select request itself:

```
select os_username, username, terminal, to_char(timestamp, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as TIME, action_name 
from dba_audit_trail
where username like upper('ernie') and action_name like upper('alter_user)
order by TIME desc;
```

There was also a problem with the design of the result in the console. Why can information be taken out of the table so crookedly? (Watch the image from above).

The actions that Ernie had done before:
[image]

Please help! I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your "problem with the design of the result in the console", by default sqlplus will ouput the columns to their max width, which will likely (as it did in your case) exceed the fixed 80-character width of the console.  You can adjust the widths with the sqlplus 'col  format  command:

Here, I first issue the same select as you (without the WHERE, which wouldn't apply to me).  It returns the same wrapped output as you got.  Then I 'format' the columns and issue the same query a second time.

```
SQL> select os_username,
  2         username,
  3         terminal,
  4         to_char(timestamp, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as TIME,
  5         action_name
  6  from dba_audit_trail
  7  ;

OS_USERNAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
USERNAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TERMINAL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TIME                ACTION_NAME
------------------- ----------------------------
oracle
SCOTT
pts/0
04-15-2021 09:40:35 CREATE TABLE


1 row selected.

SQL> --
SQL> col os_username format a10
SQL> col username    format a10
SQL> col terminal    format a10
SQL> --
SQL> --
SQL> select os_username,
  2         username,
  3         terminal,
  4         to_char(timestamp, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as TIME,
  5         action_name
  6  from dba_audit_trail
  7  ;

OS_USERNAM USERNAME   TERMINAL   TIME                ACTION_NAME
---------- ---------- ---------- ------------------- ------------
oracle     SCOTT      pts/0      04-15-2021 09:40:35 CREATE TABLE

1 row selected.
```

Sometimes even that is not enough to get the output line under the 80-character limit of the console.  In those cases you can 'SET LINESIZE nnnn', wher 'nnn' is some number that you want the linesize to be.  The console will still be limited to 80 characters, but if you 'spool' the output, you can then open in in a good text editor like notepad - outside of the 80-character console).

Looks like you could afford to spend some quality time in *[SQL*Plus User's Guide and Reference.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_six.htm#SQPUG016)*

***Edit to address question of 'can I get this data'?***

If the init parm AUDIT_TRAIL is set to 'DB,EXTENDED', then the column DBA_SQL will be populated.  Setting AUDIT_TRAIL can only be done with SCOPE=SPFILE, so it will require a restart of the database.  And of course, it will not be retroactive.

Here I have two ALTER USER statements issued by SYSTEM.  The first was with AUDIT_TRAIL=DB and the second with AUDIT_TRAIL=DB,EXTENDED.

```
SQL> select
  2         username,
  3         to_char(timestamp, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as TIME,
  4         action_name,
  5         sql_text
  6  from dba_audit_trail
  7  where username='SYSTEM'
  8  ;

USERNAME   TIME                ACTION_NAME
---------- ------------------- ------------
SQL_TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SYSTEM     04-15-2021 11:02:56 ALTER USER


SYSTEM     04-15-2021 11:13:09 ALTER USER
alter user scott default tablespace users


2 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thank you! But what about a detailed description of the actions? Here you have a set table, and in my case, as you can see on my screenstays is displayed ALTER USER. Can I find out in any way what kind of change was made on the ALTER USER team? In my case, I assigned one of the users a quota, and the other of the users another table space from under the user Ernie. I would like to give a more detailed description of ALTER USER. For example: ALTER USER USER QUOTA (in case 1) and ALTER USER DEFAULT TABLESPACE (in 2nd case)

Comment: I have updated my answer to address both questions.  For brevity I dropped out some columns that were irrelevent to the demo - os_username, terminal -, but you can certainly add back whatever you want.